# Handler blocks and NSArrays - how to add to an array in a block?

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

I want to add an NSObject to an NSMutableArray inside of a a block. In the code below, the NSLog line works fine and returns the number I expect. However, when I try to add that result to an NSArray, the array is always empty when I go to access it later.

```
CMStepQueryHandler  stepQueryHandler = ^(NSInteger numberOfSteps,
NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"CMStepQueryHandler: Steps on day: %i", (int)numberOfSteps);        
    [stepsPerDay addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:numberOfSteps]];
};
```

How can I add an object to an NSMutableArray (in this case stepsPerDay) from inside of a block so that I can access it later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the block would always execute the addObject after I had tried to work with the contents of the array, I guess due to the fact that the block was executed asynchronously. The solution was to have the block call a function which worked with the array and that way I could guarantee the object would deb added to the array when the function was executed.

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine.
I suspect you forgot to initialize `stepsPerDay`. It should be

```
NSMutableArray *stepsPerDay = [NSMutableArray array];
```

As a non-related advice, you may also consider a more modern syntax

```
[stepsPerDay addObject:@(numberOfSteps)];
```